# AWS autoscaling group does not receive signal from the ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am setting up ecs service which needs ec2 instance to run containers. 
The cloud formation template that is used for setting up LaunchConfiguration and AutoScalingGroup is the following:

```
LaunchConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0d7db0e3ec32793ae
      InstanceType: t3.medium
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref SecurityGroupECS
      IamInstanceProfile: !GetAtt InstanceProfileContainer.Arn
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Sub:
            - |
              #!/bin/bash
              # Set any ECS agent configuration options
              echo ECS_CLUSTER=${Cluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
              /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e 0 --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ${AutoScalingGroupId} --region ${AWS::Region}
            - Cluster: !Ref Cluster
              AutoScalingGroupId: ECSAutoScalingGroup
  AutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: ECSAutoScalingGroup
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref SubnetECSPrivate
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref LaunchConfiguration
      MinSize: 0
      MaxSize: 1
      DesiredCapacity: 1
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT3M
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
        WillReplace: true
```

During deployment the following problem appeared:

```
Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
```

It looks like ec2 instance does not send signal despite the bash script looks ook. At the same time ec2 instance is up and running according to web console

1. What is the best place to find userdata logs to see what happens during startup (while ec2 instance is not public, hence is not reachable using ssh)?
2. Did I write the correct bash script for sending success signal?
3. If the script is correct, what are the possible issues that cause this?

Comment: Is the instance being launched in a **Private Subnet**? Can it connect to the Internet (via Security Group, NAT Gateway, Route Table, Internet Gateway) to send the signal?

Comment: If you are unable to SSH to the instance to check the logs, you could try connecting via [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html), which uses an agent to connect outwards to the Internet. Alternatively, you could send logs to CloudWatch Logs. See: [View CloudFormation Logs in the Console | AWS DevOps Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/view-cloudformation-logs-in-the-console/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein. Yep, the instance is in the private subnet, but it has access to the internet through NAT gateway which is allowed to talk to Internet through Internet Gateway

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to login to the instance and look at the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` file. Try using Session Manager to connect to it. Otherwise, you can login to an instance in the public subnet, then SSH into the private instance.

Comment: Shouldn't the resource in cfn-signal command be AutoScalingGroup instead of AutoScalingGroupId because AutoScalingGroupId is not a valid resource id?

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 AutoScalingGroupId will be replaced with the name of the group which in this case is ECSAutoScalingGroup. Worth to mention that previously I tried both the name and the id of the autoscaling group, but it did not work